# Installing SSL certificate - Error DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=94, too big

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

Trying to install an SSL certificate for a web application that runs on Tomcat.

when I run this command I get the error below:

D:\jdk1.6.0_30\bin>keytool -import -alias root -keystore tomcat2.keystore -trust
cacerts -file D:/SSL/gdroot-g2.crt
Enter keystore password:

keytool error: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Unable to initialize, ja
va.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=94, too big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the certificate is expected by default having DER format

you can import the pem/crt file with parameter `-rfc`

```
keytool -import -alias root -keystore tomcat2.keystore -trustcacerts -rfc -file D:/SSL/gdroot-g2.crt
```